# How to retrieve the selected text in Label from ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, label

This is my front-end code for my product in `ListView`.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card shadow">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="title">
                <asp:Label ID="lblprodId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("flavourID") %>' Style="display: normal"></asp:Label>

                <h3><%# Eval("flavourName") %></h3>
            </div>
            <img class="prodImg" src="pizza/<%# Eval("flavourImg") %>" alt="Card image cap">
            <center><div class="btn"><div><asp:Button ID="btnShowOrder" runat="server" Text="Order This" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnShowOrder_Click"/></div></div></center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my .cs file.

```
protected void btnShowOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in prodList.Items)
    {
        int index = 0;
        Label lblprodId = prodList.Items[index].FindControl("lblprodId") as Label;
        Session["prodID"] = lblprodId.Text.ToString();
    }
    //Session["prodID"] = lblprodId.Text;
}
```

Right now I'm able to retrive the product id of the 1st item only. Eventhough i click on other product the id which display in my cart is the 1st product ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `foreach` loop. You can use the `NamingContainer` to get the correct value.

```
protected void btnShowOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to a button
    Button btn = sender as Button;

    //get the current item from the listview namingcontainer
    ListViewItem item = btn.NamingContainer as ListViewItem;

    //use findcontrol to locate the label in that item
    Label lbl = item.FindControl("lblprodId") as Label;

    //show result in label outside listview
    Label1.Text = lbl.Text;
}
```

ASPX

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="lblprodId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("flavourID") %>'></asp:Label>

        <asp:Button ID="btnShowOrder" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnShowOrder_Click"/>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: tried i still retrieve the 1st product ID instead of the product ID that i click.

Comment: That is not possible. Try my code on a separate page and see that it works. Did you bind data to the ListView in an `IsPostBack` check.

Comment: I'm able to retrieve my product ID. Tks :)